# How can I get other users info(username, firstname) by id? [Keycloak]

Tags: java, api, keycloak, user-management

How can I get user keycloak attributes (username, firstname, email...) based on user id? 
The user I'm using in the Keycloak session has already the role *view-users* assigned so I should be able to list at least all users, is there any Keycloak class that I can use?

What I'm trying to achieve here is to avoid to replicate the keycloak users database to another local database, but doesn't seem possible to access any other user info, besides the one in the current session...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the Admin REST API. The detailed description of the relevant API is available [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource). Also you can use the JAVA wrapper API. Please find couple of examples below.

**Example 1, REST:**

Get an access token:

```
curl \
  -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
  -d "username=admin" \
  -d "password=secret" \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

Get all users:

```
curl \
  -H "Authorization: bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...." \
  "http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/users"
```

Sample output:

```
[
     {
        "id":"349f67de-36e6-4552-ac54-e52085109616",
        "username":"admin",
        "enabled":true,
        ...
     },
     {
        "id":"08afb701-fae5-40b4-8895-e387ba1902fb",
        "username":"lbalev",
        "enabled":true,
        ....
     }
  ]
```

Get a user based by user id:

```
curl \
  -H "Authorization: bearer eyJhbGciOiJSU...." \
  "http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/users/349f67de-36e6-4552-ac54-e52085109616"
```

**Example 2, JAVA API:**

Get a user based on user ID:

```
public class TestUserAccess {

  private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8080/auth";
  private static final String REALM = "master";
  private static final String USERNAME = "admin";
  private static final String PASSWORD = "secret";
  private static final String CLIENT_ID = "admin-cli";

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder
        .builder()
        .serverUrl(SERVER_URL)
        .realm(REALM)
        .username(USERNAME)
        .password(PASSWORD)
        .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
        .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build())
        .build();

    UsersResource usersResource = keycloak.realm(REALM).users();
    UserResource userResource = usersResource.get("08afb701-fae5-40b4-8895-e387ba1902fb");
    System.out.println(userResource.toRepresentation().getEmail());
  }
}
```

The relevant dependencies for the example above are (please note that the versions might not be up-to-date):

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-admin-client', version: '3.3.0.CR2'
    compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jaxrs', version: '3.1.4.Final'
    compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-client', version: '3.1.4.Final'
    compile group: 'org.jboss.resteasy', name: 'resteasy-jackson2-provider', version: '3.1.4.Final'
}
```

Comment: can u exaplain why the url is localhost:8080, from my understanding keyclock has a different ip address something like http://43.224.110.84:8080

Answer (score 12):

The is simple method as well, because in above answer all the user info is getting fetched which is not the proper way because in case thousands of users it will be heavy call.

so just pass username as query parameter

```
GET: http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/{real-name}/users?username=testUser
```

make sure you user admin access token for the call

Comment: Best solution for searching by username, thanks! Unfortunately its not working with id param.

Comment: For retrieving user representation by user id use `/auth/admin/realms/{realm-name}/users/{id}` endpoint. [Source](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/rest-api/#_user_resources)

Comment: @Shmuser in case u can't find a specific, existing user, you might not have the permissions to see this user or you are in the wrong realm, e.g. u use master in the url instead of the realm the user is actually in.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @Nikhil Shinde for sharing the restapi endpoint.

Like he said the below will give look a like users.

```
GET: http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/{real-name}/users?username=testUser
```

If you want exact username match, then try with exact=true

```
GET: http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/{real-name}/users?username=testUser&exact=true
```

Source : https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource

Comment: You answer seems very similar with the which one that you mentionned. What did you add to it ?

Comment: The second url gives the exact user rather than a list of look a like user.

Comment: thanks, this works for me: http://IP:8080/admin/realms/master/users?exact=true&username=myuser  in my v17.01 put /auth in path give me error.

Answer (score 3):

You can just simply search by id in search bar of the keycloak admin console,
like this,
[image]

```
id:ac796f21-c4ef-4182-a70a-970bac598bd6
```

Use `id:` before enter the user id.

if user id is 12345

**Search by id,**

```
id:12345
```

**Assume you have this user**
user01 - gayankod@gmail.com

**Search by email or username with wildcard**

```
user%
%gmail.com
%kod%
```

Comment: Nice! Works flawless! I would like to know more about this. Does anybody know if this is somewhere in the docs? Cant find it there.

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak Rest API

Version > 17 Quarkus base

```
// Below will return's look a like users
GET: http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/{real-name}/users?username=testUser

// Below Will return's exact same user
GET: http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/{real-name}/users?username=testUser&exact=true
```

For Legacy Version use /auth/ in url

```
// Below will return's look a like users
GET: http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/{real-name}/users?username=testUser

// Below Will return's exact same user
GET: http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/{real-name}/users?username=testUser&exact=true
```